# MKMapView - Convert users co-ordinate to a string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

I'd like to grab the users location as a co-ordinate and convert it to a string -- any ideas? I've searched and can't find any solution.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean string as in 
`NSString *latAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.latitude];`

or do you mean convert the lat/long into a street address? (reverse geocode)